# How do I run bat file inside cmd using tash scheduler

Tags: windows, batch

How do I run bat file inside cmd using tash scheduler. I've tried this one
`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe C:\synchronization.bat`
And doesn't working.

Comment: I found working method 
`cmd /k mybatfile.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
cmd /c mybatfile.bat
```

to run a command and terminate the cmd shell or

```
cmd /k mybatfile.bat
```

to run a command and keep the cmd shell.